# String separation from value

Tags: string, oracle, separator

please can you help. I have this:

[image]

And I want to have this:

[image]

And this:

[image]

In separate queries.

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: PlSql Oracle 12g

Comment: What does "in separate queries" mean? Which rules lead from *source* to *target*? Are there always exactly 3 "values" in COLUMNONE? Do you want to extract 1st and 3rd value, or 1st and last, or ...?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please show your current code and describe what's wrong with it

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
select  *
from yourtable
where columnone in
 (select regexp_substr('UserOne,UserTwo,UserThree','[^,]+', 1, level)
  from dual
  connect BY regexp_substr('UserOne,UserTwo,UserThree', '[^,]+', 1, level)
  is not null);
```

It very much seems that you can just run the subquery

```
select regexp_substr('UserOne,UserTwo,UserThree','[^,]+', 1, level)
from dual
connect BY regexp_substr('UserOne,UserTwo,UserThree', '[^,]+', 1, level)
is not null
offset 1 rows fetch next 1 rows only
```

change the values given to `offset` and `fetch` in your different queries.

see https://www.oratable.com/regex-split-comma-separated-string/